# How to overlay/display part of a React component over another React component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a create-react-app where I have say 2 separate components. I want to display part of the Footer component on top the Home component.
My App.js looks like this:

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
   <>
   <Home/>
   <Footer/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to display the div containing "Our Partners" of the Footer component within the home component.

Footer.js

```
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <section className="footer-section">
      <div className="footer-container">
        <h2 className="footer-heading">
          OUR
          <br />
          PARTNERS
        </h2>
      </div>
     
    </section>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

Footer.css

```
.footer-section {
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background-color: #410099;
  }
  
  .footer-container {
    top: 0;
    z-index:999;
    margin-top: -250px;
    padding-top: 55px;
    padding-bottom: 55px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-right: 55px;
    padding-left: 55px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  
  .footer-heading {
    color: #410099;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
```

Home.js code is irrelevant but here's the css:

Home.css

```
.home-section {
  padding-top: 140px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  background-image: grey;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  }
```

What I want to achieve:
[image]

What I have achieved (thought negative margin was enough but apparently its not)
[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.footer-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 80% 10%;
  align-items: center
}

.footer-border {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80% 20%
}

.footer-border-top {
  background: purple;
}

.footer-border-bottom {
  background: blue
}

.footer-content {
  padding-left: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="footer-section">
  <div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer-border">
      <div class="footer-border-top"></div>
      <div class="footer-border-bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-content">
      <h2 class="footer-heading">
        OUR
        <br /> PARTNERS
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-border">
      <div class="footer-border-top"></div>
      <div class="footer-border-bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

there you go :)

BTW, the values are arbitrary *(e.g. 'gap: 4em', 'grid-template-rows: 80% 20%'...)*, feel free to change them if you need to.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your input but this is not what exactly I wanted. I will have other content than just our partner and need to have the blue border around the entire footer section, just the top div containing our partner should be popped and overlaid with home. Thanks a lot for trying though :)

Comment: hello, I edited my solution. instead of making the footer-container a flex container i made it a grid. Should be exactly what you wanted.... I hope so